# How to store query result in a variable and call it in another function Node JS

Tags: javascript

Basically, I am trying to store a query result in a variable and then call it from another function but it does not work.

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: '',
  database: 'userdb'
});

con.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM tblusers", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    setValue(result);

    function setValue(value) {
      someVar = value;
      console.log(someVar);
    }
  });
});
```

```
data: {
labels: ["Delivered","Warehouse","Out for delivery"],
datasets: [
{
data: [someVar, 2, 0],
borderWidth: [1, 1, 1],
backgroundColor: [brandPrimary,"rgba(75,192,192,1)","#FFCE56"],
hoverBackgroundColor[brandPrimary,"rgba(75,192,192,1)","#FFCE56"]}]}
```

Comment: I believe what you need to do is to add `var someVar;` at the top of your file. This way the variable become "visible" for the whole file not only inside the `setValue` function. Could you also share the code where you are trying to use `someVar` variable and the error that you are getting, so we have more context on the issue ?

Comment: The first code is working perfectly, it store query result to someVar, the problem is when I call it in another function, it does not work, example -> data: [someVar, 2,0]

Comment: Can you attach a code where you do the `call it in another function` ?

Comment: You should read about scope in JavaScript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp @Telman comment is right, you should declare a variable in the global scope and then simply assign your query result to it.

Comment: This is my all code: https://www.azedpress.com/code.js

Comment: @xromaz do the chart initialization (`var myPieChart = new Chart(PIECHART`) after you called `setValue`. Right now you are doing it on `$(document).ready` which is too soon, at this point your data is is till empty.